# API access, Hashing query, possibly related to character encoding

Tags: r, hash, character-encoding, rcurl, digest-authentication

Its going to be impossible to provide a reproducible example for this as it has to do with accessing a particular API - apologies in advance. I am trying to access the edinburgh fringe festivals API through R. The [documentation](https://api.edinburghfestivalcity.com/documentation) says the following:

> **Authentication**
>
> An access key is required for all requests to the API and can be
>   obtained by registration. This key, combined with the signature
>   explained below, is required to get any access to the API. If you do
>   not provide an access key, or provide an invalid key or signature, the
>   server will return an `HTTP 403` error.
>
> Your secret token is used to calculate the correct signature for each
>   API request and must never be disclosed. Once issued, it is never
>   transmitted back or forward. The API server holds a copy of your
>   secret token, which it uses to check that you have signed each request
>   correctly.
>
> You calculate the signature using the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm:
>
> - Build the full API request URL, including your access key but excluding the server domain - eg `/events?festival=book&key=12345`. See
>     the note below on URL encoding.
> - Calculate the hmac hash of the url using the sha1 algorithm and your secret token as the key.
> - Append the hex-encoded hash to your url as the signature parameter
>
> **URL encoding in queries**
>
> You should calculate the signature after URL-encoding any parameters -
>   for example, to search for the title "Mrs Brown" you would first build
>   the URL `/events?title=Mrs%20Brown&key=12345` and then sign this string
>   and append the signature.
>
> **Signature encoding**
>
> Some languages - notably C# - default to encoding hashes in UTF-16.
>   Ensure your signature is encoded in plain ASCII hex or it will not be
>   valid.

What I have tried so far is below:

```
    library(digest)
    library(jsonlite)
    source("authentication.R") # credentials stored here
```

create the query string

```
    query <- paste0('/events?festival=demofringe&size=20&from=1&key=', API_KEY)
```

create the hashed query

```
    sig <- hmac(SECRET_SIGNING_KEY, query, algo="sha1")
```

create the final url

```
    url <- paste0('https://api.edinburghfestivalcity.com', query, '&signature=', sig)
```

submit to the API

```
    results <- fromJSON(url)
```

and I get the error:

```
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 417.
```

I'm not sure that the signature is ASCII encoded as per the documentation. Does anyone know how to debug this situation? I have tried `iconv()` to try and convert the encoding and when I call `Encoding()` on the character object it returns `"unknown"`. I have also tried saving both files in RStudio with "save with encoding" set to ASCII and I have tried sourcing the authentications with `encoding = "ASCII"`.

Incidentally when I paste the final url into a browser, I get the following error:

```
Invalid Accept header value. ['application/json', 'application/json;ver=2.0'] are supported
```

Comment: Could it be that you forgot an & between from=1 and key? Shouldn't it be ` query <- paste0('/events?festival=demofringe&size=20&from=1&key=', API_KEY)`

Comment: thank you for spotting that mistake. i fixed this and now i get the error `Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 417.`. I'll edit the question to reflect this change.

Comment: You're welcome. We've all made these typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a server error. It should understand that

```
Accept: application/json, text/*, */*
```

Matches `application/json`. Note that instead of modifying jsonlite, it is beter to manually retrieve the response form the server, and *then* feed it to jsonlite.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
req <- GET(your_url, accept("application/json")
json <- content(req, as = 'text')
data <- fromJSON(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved this problem by editing the `jsonlite::fromJSON()` function. namely the line

```
curl::handle_setheaders(h, Accept = "application/json, text/*, */*")
```

I changed to

```
curl::handle_setheaders(h, Accept = "application/json")
```

I then also had to point to the internal functions with `jsonlite:::`. Now it works fine.